# php mail not working on rackspace cloud

Tags: sendmail, php

i have this rackspace server, and i installed sendmail there. the sendmail is configured to send emails using  sendgrid.

so the sendmail works via the terminal, but the php mail function returns false, and doesnt send any emails. the sendmail path is correctly set in the php.ini too.

I have this in the /etc/php.ini,

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
```

when i take a phpinfo() using

```
<?php

phpinfo()
```

it returns

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
```

Comment: two quick ideas: reload your config file and double-check your permissions

Comment: permissions what permissions really ?

Comment: Verify you're using the `php.ini` that you are editing, when `phpinfo()` shows, check the `php.ini` is showing as `/etc/php.ini`. Failing that, this question might get more answers on serverfault.com

Comment: thats verified, it is using the correct one

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-do-i-test-php-smtp-functionality here's the code they refer to use in order to get your mails working on the Rackspace Cloud Sites...

**Non-SSL**

```
<?php
require_once "Mail.php";


$from = "Web Master <webmaster@example.com>";
$to = "Nobody <nobody@example.com>";
$subject = "Test email using PHP SMTP\r\n\r\n";
$body = "This is a test email message";

$host = "mail.emailsrvr.com";
$username = "webmaster@example.com";
$password = "yourPassword";

$headers = array ('From' => $from,
  'To' => $to,
  'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
  array ('host' => $host,
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
  echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
  echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
}
```

**With SSL**

```
<?php
require_once "Mail.php";

$from = "Web Master <webmaster@example.com>";
$to = "Nobody <nobody@example.com>";
$subject = "Test email using PHP SMTP with SSL\r\n\r\n";
$body = "This is a test email message";

$host = "ssl://secure.emailsrvr.com";
$port = "465";
$username = "webmaster@example.com";
$password = "yourPassword";

$headers = array ('From' => $from,
  'To' => $to,
  'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
  array ('host' => $host,
    'port' => $port,
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
  echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
  echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
}
?>
```

Relevant Question

[php mail function not sending emails / taking too long to send emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771645/php-mail-function-not-sending-emails-taking-too-long-to-send-emails)

Also over here they suggest some of what the issue is.

http://www.joshuawinn.com/huge-email-delays-on-rackspace-cloud-sites-dont-use-php-mail

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.

Comment: Sorry Kev, I've updated my post to reflect what you requested.