# Ajax form taking a very long time to send emails

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, contact-form

I have an Ajax contact form on my site which actually currently works but the email that it compiles from the form is taking around 50 minutes to arrive in my inbox, here is the code, does anyone know what could be causing this excessive time gap?

Jquery

```
$("#contactForm").submit(function(event){
        // cancels the form submission
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm();
    });

    function submitForm(){
        // Initiate Variables With Form Content
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var message = $("#message").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "form-process.php",
            data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message,
            success : function(text){
                if (text == "success"){
                    formSuccess();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    function formSuccess(){
        $( "#msgSubmit" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="form-container">
            <form role="form" id="contactForm">
                <input id="name" class="input" type="text" placeholder="Your name" name="name">
                <input id="email" class="input" type="text" placeholder="Contact email address" name="email">
                <textarea id="message" class="input message" placeholder="What would you like to discuss?" name="message"></textarea>
                <input id="form-submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="Send Message" name="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$EmailTo = "contact@etcetcetc.co.uk";
$Subject = "New Message Received";

// prepare email body text
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);

// redirect to success page
if ($success){
   echo "success";
}else{
    echo "invalid";
}

?>
```

Comment: are you sending mail emails? what OS is your server? a linux or a windows one?

Comment: I am sending mails from the contact form straight to my inbox. I believe the server is linux through a shared cloud hosting platform.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php mail function not sending emails / taking too long to send emails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771645/php-mail-function-not-sending-emails-taking-too-long-to-send-emails)

Comment: Has nothing to do with the Ajax portion of it...

Comment: Can I presume this is something to do with my mailserver / hosting then?

Comment: yes it has to do with server

Comment: Everything is sorted now, it seemed to just require a little bit of time to bed in and start working properly, now the delay is milliseconds...